# Moving array elements to end of array by sorting

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

If I have an array like so (it could be any combination of numbers):

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4, 2, 1);
```

I want to move all the elements that equal **4** to the end of the array, while preserving the order of the other elements, so ideally my resulting array would be:

```
1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 2, 1, 4, 4
```

I thought I could acheve this by using a sort function:

```
uasort($arr, function($a, $b){
    return $b == 4 ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Which moves the "4" elements to the end, but ruins the order of the other elements, this is my result with the above code:

```
2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 2, 1, 4, 4
```

How should my sorting handler function look? / Is there a better way to achieve this than sorting the array?

Note; I want to preserve my array keys (hence `uasort`)

[**eval.in**](https://eval.in/295489)

Comment: Your handler doesn't take into account `$a`. Just put in a clause for 4, and then use the handler you'd use for a normal sort. Replace the  `1` with `($a < $b ? -1 : 1)` (doesn't take equality into account, of course).

Comment: @halfer I didn't think I would need to since I don't want any 'logical' sorting. Your solution doesn't give me the desired result, but thanks.

Comment: Ah right, I missed that. OK, the callback sorting methods feel inappropriate for that - Rizier has a good approach though!

Comment: @halfer I disagree. I think this is a form of sorting, however unorthodox.

Comment: It is a form of sorting, but I _think_ you would need to declare all other comparisons as "don't care", which may be an undefined behaviour. Hmm, tell you what though, try swapping your `1` to a `0` in your handler above, to see if that keeps all other comparison pairs as they are? Worth a shot (though for maintainability/understandability I think I would still go with Rizier's).

Comment: @halfer in case you're interested, [my answer uses uasort](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28835966/2088135)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it with `uasort`:

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4, 2, 1);

uasort($arr, function($a, $b){
    if ($a == 4) return -1;
    if ($b == 4) return 1;
    return 0;
});

$arr = array_reverse($arr, true);

print_r($arr);
```

The `true` argument to `array_reverse` preserves the keys in the array. The `return 0` is optional but improves clarity in my opinion.

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [1] => 2
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 5
    [7] => 2
    [8] => 1
    [2] => 4
    [6] => 4
)
```

The fact that some of the keys corresponding to the same value are mixed up is unavoidable.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks Tom. I have changed your last line to `$arr = array_reverse($arr, true);`.

Comment: Nice and clean... would be better (maybe) if you add `array_values()` to reindex? like: `$arr = array_values(array_reverse($arr, true));`

Comment: @gmo I think that the OP was hoping to preserve the keys in the array. If you want to reset them, you can simply remove the `true` argument to `array_reverse`.

Answer (score 4):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $arr = array(1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4, 2, 1);

    foreach($arr as $k => $v) {

        if($v == 4) {
            unset($arr[$k]);
            $arr[$k] = $v;  
        }

    }

    print_r($arr);

?>
```

Output:

```
//before 
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 4 [3] => 2 [4] => 3 [5] => 5 [6] => 4 [7] => 2 [8] => 1 ) 
//after                    ^ key ^  value                      ^ key ^ value  
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [3] => 2 [4] => 3 [5] => 5 [7] => 2 [8] => 1 [2] => 4 [6] => 4 )
                                                                      //^     ^  ^     ^
```

Comment: Thanks Rizier but this won't preserve my array keys.

Comment: @George updated my answer, should keep the keys now!

Comment: Thanks Rizier, I was hoping someone would come up with a sort handler that would do what I needed. This is the next best thing though.

Answer (score 1):

How about this...??

```
<?php

$arr = array(1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4, 2, 1);
$temp= array();
foreach($arr as $index => $value){
  if($value == 4) {
    array_push($temp, $value);    
    unset ($arr[$index]);
  }
}
$result = array_merge($arr, $temp);
var_dump($result);
```

Gave me this:

```
array(9) {[0]=>int(1) [1]=>int(2) [2]=>int(2) [3]=>int(3) [4]=>int(5) [5]=>int(2) [6]=>int(1) [7]=>int(4)   [8]=>int(4) }
```

Comment: Thanks tramp, but this is seems like overkill when you consider Riziers answer.

Comment: Yup...I know... I agree... Saw it after submitting mine... Was caught with a syntax error in unset... I should say "Impressive work" @Riziers...

Answer (score 0):

Try with...

1. count([array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)())
2. [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)()
3. [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)()
4. [array_fill](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php)()
5. [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)()

Example: https://eval.in/295552

CODE

```
<?php

// initial array
$arr = array(1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4, 2, 1);

// key to move (as a new array for array_diff)
$key_removed = array(4);

// count the number of repetitions (for array_fill)
$key_repetitions = count(array_keys($arr, $key_removed[0], true));

// new temp_array without the removed key
$temp_arr1 = array_diff($arr, $key_removed);

// reorder array index
$temp_arr1 = array_values($temp_arr1);

// add to temp_array the removed key `key_repetitions` number of times
$temp_arr2 = array_fill(count($temp_arr1) + 1, $key_repetitions, $key_removed[0]);

// merge both
$arr = array_merge($temp_arr1, $temp_arr2);

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: Thanks gmo, but this doesn't give the desired result.